# Gunicorn for Django project without virtual environment

Tags: django, gunicorn

I was trying to deploy my Django project with Gunicorn but the tutorial is very messy and even though the example worked, the real project is not working. Do I need to configure a gunicorn file or make some changes in project wsgi file?
here is my wsgi file-

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "ChemicalSimilarities.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I am using this command to try to run gunicorn for debugging too -

```
gunicorn ChemicalSimilarities.wsgi:application--debug --log-level debug
```

The error that I am getting is this -

```
ImportError: No module named ChemicalSimilarities.wsgi
[2018-02-14 16:41:47 +0000] [26512] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 26512)
[2018-02-14 16:41:47 +0000] [26508] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2018-02-14 16:41:47 +0000] [26508] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

Comment: Gunicorn uses the normal python module resolution. So when you start gunicorn, you have to do it from the parent directory of `ChemicalSimilarities` or have that directory in the shell `PATH`. And there should be a file called `./ChemicalSimilarities/wsgi.py`

Comment: Not using virtual environment will typically make module resolution more complicated, unless you are running this inside a docker container. You should read up on how python import statements and sys.path works.